# Apply style to child content in WPF XAML with a template

Tags: wpf, xaml, templates, styles, children

I'm using a `ListView`to display a menu. I want to apply a style to all `ListViewItem`. So far I have succeeded in one part of the concern but I would like to improve to avoid code replication. Here where I am :

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="_listViewItemStyle" TargetType="ListViewItem">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
                    <Border x:Name="Bd"
                       ...                  
                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                       ...
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```

And then use the style like that :

```
 <ListView x:Name="_listViewMenu"
     Background="Transparent"
     BorderBrush="Transparent"
     ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
         <ListViewItem Style="{StaticResource _listViewItemStyle}">
             <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"
                       Width="230"
                       Margin="10,0,0,0">
                 <Image Width="30" 
                       Source="Images/Settings.png"
                       Stretch="Uniform"/>
                 <TextBlock Text="Paramètres"
                       Margin="25,0,0,0"
                       Style="{StaticResource _fontStyle}"/>
             </StackPanel>
         </ListViewItem>
 </ListView>
```

As you can see there are some stuff that I imagine I can avoid to duplicate if I have 50 ListViewItems, let's say :

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"
                       Width="230"
                       Margin="10,0,0,0">
```

or

```
<Image Width="30"
     ...
Stretch="Uniform"/>
```

etc...

How to include in the style `_listViewItemStyle` all required properties to format StackPanel, Image, textbox, etc... of the ListViewItem?

Thanks.

Comment: Typical in WPF for such a job is to use a Data Template in the ItemTemplate property.
But for your task, you do not need to "hand" write the ListViewItem list in XAML.
It is typical to create a class with data for one ListViewItem. Then collections with instances of this class. And binding this collection to the ItemsSource property.
Then you have everything in the code and XAML will become much easier and more convenient.

Comment: Sorry I'm new to WPF but I'm not sure to understand. Here these ListViewItem are item in a menu. I can have several item, for exemple Home, Settings, Employees, etc...This is the UI, so I was thinking we have to stay in the view, am I wrong?

Comment: @Manta: Move the `StackPanel` to an `ItemTemplate` and bind or set the `ItemsSource` property of the `ListView` to a collection of your items.

Comment: How do these items differ from each other? Judging by the code, only text and an icon. So create a simple type with two properties: string and ImageSource. And to display this type, DataTempate will be used with the necessary UI elements.

Answer (score 1):

You can define a class which has necessary properties and use it as item type of collection for `ItemsSource` which may be in view (xaml or code behind). Such class would be as follows.

```cs
public class SourceItem
{
    public string? ImagePath { get; init; }
    public string? Text { get; init; }
}
```

Then, if you just want to show items, `ItemsControl` would be suffice. I don't know how you intend to use Triggers though.

```xml
<ItemsControl Background="Blue" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
    <local:SourceItem ImagePath="Images/Settings.png" Text="Paramètres"/>
    ...

    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Border x:Name="Bd">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"
                            Width="230"
                            Margin="10,0,0,0">
                    <Image Width="30"
                           Source="{Binding ImagePath, Mode=OneTime}"
                           Stretch="Uniform"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text, Mode=OneTime}"
                               Margin="25,0,0,0"
                               Style="{StaticResource _fontStyle}"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </Border>

            <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                ...
            </DataTemplate.Triggers>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Comment: I have used this template and now, as you said, I need to bind command. I have add `ICommand? MyCommand` in SourceItem but now how to bind this in the DataTemplate for a mouse click?

Comment: Ok, got it : `Inputbindings`

Answer (score -1):

In addition to the answer from @emoacht, you will need the following `InputBindings`:

```
<Border.InputBindings>
    <MouseBinding Command="{Binding ItemCommand}" MouseAction="LeftClick"/>
</Border.InputBindings>
```